# Javascript loop, counter equals 0 two times in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

So I am working on a little slideshow script. The problem is that `i` equals `0` two times in a loop. In the following code piece of code:

```
for (var i = 0; children.length > i; i++ ) {

        (function(children, i, time){
            setTimeout (function(){
                // fade out current slide
                setTimeout(function(){
                        fadeItOut(children[i]);
                    },2000);

                // wait for the execution of the if statement
                var nextSlide = window.setInterval(function(){
                    // if the current slide is not the first slide
                    // and if the slide before current slide has faded out
                   if(children[i-1] && children[i-1].style.opacity === "") {
                       // show the next slide
                        children[i].style.display = 'block';
                       nextSlide = window.clearInterval(nextSlide);
                   } 

                    // if the current slide is the first slide
                    else if (i === 0) {
                        // just show it
                        children[i].style.display = 'block';
                    }
                },1);

            }, time);

        })(children, i,  time)

        time += 2000;
    }
```

This is the whole script:

```
var magic = window.setInterval(function(){
if (document.readyState === "complete") {

    // globals
    var children = document.getElementById('slide-container').children,
        time = 2000;

    // fadeout function
    function fadeItOut (element) {
        var child = element;
        // get the current opacity
        function opacityNo (element) {
            if (element.style.opacity === "") {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return element.style.opacity;
            }
        };

        child.style.opacity = opacityNo(child);
        //decrase opacity to 0 by 1
        var decrase = window.setInterval(function(){
            child.style.opacity -= 1/100;
            if (child.style.opacity <= 0.01) {
                child.style.opacity = "";    
                child.style.display = 'none';    
                decrase = window.clearInterval(decrase);
            }
        },1);
     };


    // start the show
    for (var i = 0; children.length > i; i++ ) {

        (function(children, i, time){
            setTimeout (function(){
                // fade out current slide
                setTimeout(function(){
                        fadeItOut(children[i]);
                    },2000);

                // wait for the execution of the if statement
                var nextSlide = window.setInterval(function(){
                    // if the current slide is not the first slide first 
                    // and if the slide before current slide has faded out
                   if(children[i-1] && children[i-1].style.opacity === "") {
                       // show the next slide
                        children[i].style.display = 'block';
                       nextSlide = window.clearInterval(nextSlide);
                   } 

                    // if the current slide is the first slide
                    else if (i === 0) {
                        // just show it
                        children[i].style.display = 'block';
                    }
                },1);

            }, time);

        })(children, i,  time)

        time += 2000;
    }


    // end the show
    console.log(time);   
    magic = window.clearInterval(magic);

} else {
    console.log("...");
}
}, 1000);
```

The point is that it waits until the previous slide fully faded out before showing the next slide.

I use it along with this HTML: `

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="slide-container">
        <li style="display: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8qBcyzc.jpg"></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/oxMTFTF.png"></li>
        <li style="display: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/JTM6Yqg.jpg"></li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

`

When you run it you will see that when the first image has faded out, it appears immediately again.

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/xHn4x)

Comment: What debugging have you performed?

Comment: Can you put it in a JSfiddle? As Lightness suggests, I think each line needs to be debugged to see what is happening. I suspect the issue is in the setTimeout()

Comment: @User970008 JF: http://jsfiddle.net/xHn4x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dZBG4/)

It is working by removing `else if` statement where you verify if `i === 0`. This verification must be done in the previous `if` statement.

```
if((children[i-1] && children[i-1].style.opacity === "") || i === 0) {
    // show the next slide
    children[i].style.display = 'block';
    window.clearInterval(nextSlide);
}
```

I'm suggesting you to play around with `z-index` by placing the next image behind the active one. This will prevent the background to be shown and the transition will be nicely.

Comment: It works great. But wasn't the mine version just a longer one from the one you gave there? Shouldn't it work as well?

Comment: The difference between your version is that you don't clear the interval in your `else if` statement. `window.clearInterval(nextSlide);`

Comment: You're totally correct. Thanks for pointing that out and the tip.